# Show if $x^2$ is divisible by $5$ then $x$ is divisible by $5$ as well

Tags: real-analysis

> Show if $x^2$ is divisible by $5$ then $x$ is divisible by $5$ as well

I tried to do this with contrapositive but I feel like it doesn't work. I start with if $x$ is not divisible by $5$ then $x^2$ is not divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a prime $p$ divides a product $ab$, then it divides one of the two factors $a$ or $b$.

This is one of the most important properties of prime numbers.

Now take $a=b=x$.

Comment: +1. Just to nitpick. "This is one of the most important properties of prime numbers." -- This is the definition of a prime number.

Comment: @user17762, there are many ways to define prime *numbers*. This is the one that plays the nicest with the definition of prime ideal, but having taught the subject to newbies many times, I know that it is not the most easily grasped.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$x^2 \equiv \begin{cases} 0 \pmod5 & \text{if $x \equiv 0 \pmod5$}\\1 \pmod5 & \text{if $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$}\\-1 \pmod5 & \text{if $x \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$}\end{cases}$$
Now conclude what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the prime factors of $ x $ and $ x^2 $.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2$ is divisible by $5$ then it ends by $0$ or $5$ in decimal notation. Therefore, $x$ has to end by $0$ or $5$ (easy check) and, therefore, is divisible by $5$. QED